# How to access struct member via pointer to pointer

Tags: c, structure

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} stu, *pstdu;

void func(stu **pst);

int main() {
    stu *pst;
    pst = (stu*)malloc(sizeof(stu));
    pst->a = 10;
    func(&pst);
}

void func(stu **pstu) {
    /* how to access the variable a */
}
```

1) Want to access the structure variable a by passing the pointer address,
   in above function func.

2) In following case how it will behave
   example:

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} stu, *pstdu;

void func(pstdu *pst);

int main() {
    stu *pst;
    pst = (stu*)malloc(sizeof(stu));
    pst->a = 10;
    func(&pst);
}

void func(pstdu *pstu) {
   /* how to access the variable a */
}
```

Comment: Is there a sane reason to pass a pointer to point instead of a simple pointer? Maybe you should revisit the chapter in your C book about pointers.

Comment: The only reason that comes to mind is that the memory may need to be reallocated inside `func()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to dereference the first pointer, then use the pointer-to-member operator:

```
(*pstu)->a
```

The parenthesis are required because the pointer-to-member operator has higher precedence than the dereference operator.

This is the same for both cases because `stu **` and `pstdu *` represent the same type.  As mentioned in the comments, it's considered bad practice to have a pointer in a `typedef` because it can hide that fact that a pointer is in use and can become confusing.

Comment: in 2nd case how it is working(void func(pstdu *pstu)- what is pstdu *pstu, whether *pstu is pointer to pointer

Comment: @sathish dbush didn't address the second example is its premise is wrong.

Comment: @sathish related, [stop hiding pointer types in typedefs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) and that problem becomes irrelevant. It's considered by most to be bad practice in all but a *very* limited number of circumstances (of which this is *not* one). It usually ends up accomplishing nothing but obfuscating the code and thereby making it harder to work with (which you're finding out).